# netlogo plotxy for a histogram of patch visits along x and y axis

Tags: plot, netlogo

I am new to netlogo and have a plotting question.
I implemented a simple variation on a biased random walk model. I defined
patches with a gradient of some 'attractant' and the agents accumulate near
the peak of the gradient. I am saving on each patch how many times it has
been visited.

now I would like to place two plots next to the 'world'; one below and one
to the side. In them, I want to plot the average number of visits per x coordinate or y coordinate respectively. I guess this comes down to a projection of visits along the two axis but I don't know how to implement the averaging over patches in the plotxy routine.

I am having trouble figuring out the netlogo syntax and any help or hints to
a tutorial would be appreciated. I am going to pseudo code my question below

basically, for the y axis projection, I would need something like this:

```
y= ymin to ymax

for i=ymin to ymax
x(i)= sum(visits(patches(pycor==i)))/ count(visits(patches(pycor==i)))
end

plotxy(x,y)
```

I am looking forward to hearing from you

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started.

```
to-report rows-sums
  let %rownums n-values world-height [? + min-pycor]
  let %sums map [sum [visits] of patches with [pycor = ?]] %rownums
  report (map [(list ?1 ?2)] %rownums %sums)
end

to plot-rowsums
  set-current-plot "plot01"
  clear-plot
  foreach rows-sums [plotxy item 0 ? item 1 ?]
end
```

Comment: nice, this technically works but it is really slow. I set up my world with 1000 x 500 patches because I need a smooth (sigmoidal) gradient of the attractant in my model. Is there a way to speed up the plotting? Or am I abusing netlogo with this huge world?

Comment: Yes, you can speed this up.  Most obviously, define rownums as a global rather than computing it each tick.  Less obviously, introduce a global rowsums (and of course, colsums) array, and increment a row total and a column total each time your increment a patch's visits. (Index is row number, value is sum.)